# Wordpress - How do I debug if the right parameters are added to my shortcode?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to debug if parameters are added to my shortcode. Currently, when I add a shortcode to my page and don't add a parameter it errors saying

> Updating failed

But I would like to have a more detailed error. How would I do that? I'm working with code snippets and this is a front-end snippet. I noticed that I do get the error when I run the snippet in the back-end but then my entire WP UI disappears which isn't nice. Any tips?

```
<?php

add_shortcode('taxonomy_dropdown', 'do_taxonomy_dropdown');
function do_taxonomy_dropdown($atts = [])
{
    $atts = array_change_key_case((array) $atts, CASE_LOWER);   
    if(do_validate_parameters($atts)){return;}
    $taxonomy = $atts['taxonomy'];
    $dependent = $atts['dependent'];
    return;
}

function do_validate_parameters($atts = [])
{
    $has_parameters = true;
    if(!isset($atts['taxonomy'])){
        echo "You forgot to add the taxonomy parameter.";
        $has_parameters = false;
    }

    if(!isset($atts['dependent'])){
        echo "You forgot to add the dependent parameter.";
        $has_parameters = false;
    }
    return $has_parameters;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is with the initial portion not checking for the set variable. When I run it with error logging on I see that as an issue. Try this and see if it stops the issue.

```
add_shortcode('taxonomy_dropdown', 'do_taxonomy_dropdown');
function do_taxonomy_dropdown($atts = [])
{
    $atts = array_change_key_case((array) $atts, CASE_LOWER);   
    if(do_validate_parameters($atts)){return;}
    if ( isset($atts['taxonomy'])){
        $taxonomy = $atts['taxonomy'];
    }
     if ( isset($atts['dependent'])){
      $dependent = $atts['dependent'];
    }
    return;
}

function do_validate_parameters($atts = [])
{
    $has_parameters = true;
    if(!isset($atts['taxonomy'])){
        echo "<p>You forgot to add the taxonomy parameter.</p>";
        $has_parameters = false;
    }

    if(!isset($atts['dependent'])){
        echo "<p>You forgot to add the dependent parameter.</p>";
        $has_parameters = false;
    }
    return $has_parameters;
}
```